# Cannot use vinylPaths del with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following gulp task,  basically what it does is:

- compile all .styl files
- put the result in `theme/app` folder
- minify all file in `theme/app` folder
- concatenate all file in folder `theme/app` folder to a single file
- add some license information to the file
- save result in folder`theme`
- delete all files in `theme/app` folder

I cannot make work the last step, I need to delete all files in `theme/app`.
I have not specific error, what could could be wrong in my script and how to solve it?

---

```
   gulp.task('_release-theme:compile', function () {
        gulp.src([
            'app/**/*.styl',
            '!app/**/**mixins**.styl',
            '!app/**/**variables**.styl',
        ])
        .pipe(stylus({
            compress: false,
            use: nib()
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('theme/app'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(concat('theme.css'))
        .pipe(header(fs.readFileSync('licenses/app.txt', 'utf8')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('theme/'))
        .pipe(vinylPaths(del['theme/app/**/*'])); // problem here
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`del`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) is a function. Your object property access `del['theme/app/**/*']` makes no sense here.

Instead listen for the `end` event in your stream and then delete the files using [`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf):

```
var rimraf = require('rimraf');

gulp.task('_release-theme:compile', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
        'app/**/*.styl',
        '!app/**/**mixins**.styl',
        '!app/**/**variables**.styl',
    ])
    .pipe(stylus({
        compress: false,
        use: nib()
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('theme/app'))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(concat('theme.css'))
    .pipe(header(fs.readFileSync('licenses/app.txt', 'utf8')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('theme/'))
    .on('end', function() {
      rimraf('theme/app/**/*', done);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know about rimraf!